# Singing shoshanas yaakov on Pesach

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, passover, song-poetry, haman

I have seen that some sing Shoshanas Yaakov on Pesach to commemorate the death of Haman. Can someone please direct me to an authoritative source for this custom?

See references to it here: http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/how-do-you-commemorate-the-death-of-haman
http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/when-did-haman-die

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Aba. What would you consider an "authoritative source" for this?

Comment: @Scimonster The early the better but I would settle for anything pre-ww2.

Comment: I have heard of Esther Hamalka Kugel / salad. Never heard of this Minhag, however sounds plausible.

Comment: @GershonGold The _Orach Hashulchan_ Laws of Passover 490:1 mentions adding a dish to the second day's meal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Taame Haminhagim* 579 says *Sh'ne Luchos Hab'ris* [circa 1600] indicates one should memorialize *Ester*'s meal at the meal of the second day of *Pesach*, as that was the day *Haman* was hanged. He doesn't say how to memorialize it, but I guess *Shoshanas Yaakov* is one way to do it.

*Update:* Thanks to [Aba](/users/9163/aba), who found [the *Sh'lah*](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14406&pgnum=381) (in the *hagaha* on the linked-to page). Note that it doesn't use "oughta" language like the *Taame Haminhagim*: it says, rather, that some who are careful do so. And it adds (as the *Taame Haminhagim* doesn't) that the purpose of this practice is to mention the praises of God [which makes the singing of *Shoshanas Yaakov* seem to me to be a good implementation of this practice].

Comment: "which makes the singing of Shoshanas Yaakov seem to me to be a good implementation of this practice", not 100% because the _Sh'lah_ wrote to make a remembrance of the meal Esther made which implies food, _Shosanos Yakkov_ makes no mention of the meal. I just saw the _Magen Avrahom_ in 190:1 and also he seems to understand the _Sh'lah_ as food.

Comment: on second thought the purpose of serving the extra food is to lead to singing the praises of G-d so yes just serving the food would not be enough unless you sing a song like _Shoshanas Yakkov_

Comment: a reason not to sing it .....is that they did not start singing until mordecai walked out in royal garb because they were under threat so celebrating haman demise does not deserve שושנת יעקב .....not yet