# Remembering Queen Esther on Pesach

Tags: minhag, food, passover, purim

I came across [this](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Arukh.103.6?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en#:%7E:text=6-,%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B0%D7%99%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%9D%20%D7%A9%D7%81%D6%B5%D7%A0%D6%B4%D7%99%20%D7%A9%D7%81%D6%B6%D7%9C%20%D7%A4%D6%BC%D6%B6%D7%A1%D6%B7%D7%97%2C%20%D7%99%D6%B5%D7%A9%D7%81%20%D7%9C%D6%B7%D7%A2%D6%B2%D7%A9%D7%82%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%AA%20%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B7%D7%A1%D6%BC%D6%B0%D7%A2%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%93%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%94%20%D7%90%D6%B5%D7%99%D7%96%D6%B6%D7%94%20%D7%93%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%91%D6%B8%D7%A8%2C%20%D7%9C%D6%B0%D7%96%D6%B5%D7%9B%D6%B6%D7%A8%20%D7%A1%D6%B0%D7%A2%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%93%D6%BC%D6%B7%D7%AA%20%D7%90%D6%B6%D7%A1%D6%B0%D7%AA%D6%BC%D6%B5%D7%A8%20%D7%A9%D7%81%D6%B6%D7%94%D6%B8%D7%99%D6%B0%D7%AA%D6%B8%D7%94%20%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B0%D7%99%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%9D%20%D7%96%D6%B6%D7%94%2C%20%D7%A9%D7%81%D6%B6%D7%91%D6%BC%D7%95%D6%B9%20%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B7%D7%99%D6%BC%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%9D%20%D7%A0%D6%B4%D7%AA%D6%B0%D7%9C%D6%B8%D7%94%20%D7%94%D6%B7%D7%9E%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%9F%20(%D7%AA%22%D7%A6).,-On%20the%20second) in the kitzur, about having a special food item on Pesach to remind us about the meals Queen Esther made.

> On the second day of Pesach, you should add an extra dish to the meal to remember the feast of Esther which took place on this day, for it was on this day that Haman was hanged.

Practically, I have not seen this minhag done.

Is this practiced? If it is, is there a common food that is used?

Comment: טעמי המנהגים (259) brings this in the name of the Shaloh HaKadosh. See [this related question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/56732/27180)